# Problema con comprensión de listas

Tags: python, lista

estoy aprendiendo sobre el uso de la comprensión de listas y segpun leí este sería el formato (es un ejemplo que estoy haciendo):

```
ex = ["LUNES","MARTES","JUEVES"]

d1,d2 = "LUNES", "MARTES"

for i in range(len(ex)):
    x = [d for d in [d1,d2] if d in ex[i]]
print(all(x))
```

Pero no me está generando una lista con los valores. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La comprensión de lista está mal ubicada, porque al estar dentro de un `for` se está sobreescribiendo en cada ciclo. En la última iteración (`i = 2`), dices que escriba en `x` las palabras que coincidan con `"JUEVES"`, lo cual es `ninguna` y por eso sale una lista vacía.

Las listas se pueden iterar directamente, en este caso no es necesario usar un `for` indexado.
De todas formas si fuese necesario, dejo comentadas las líneas usando índices. Solo reemplazas la línea por el comentario y listo.

```
x = []
for elem in ex: #for i in range(len(ex)): # <-- con índice
    for d in [d1, d2]:
        if d == elem: #if d == ex[i]: # <-- con índice
            x.append(d)
print(all(x))
print(x)
```

El mismo código (sin los `print()`) en comprensión de listas:

```python
x = [d for elem in ex for d in [d1, d2] if elem == d]
```

Comment: oh, ya veo, ¡gracias! :)